# Помощь в размещении колонок bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Извините за глупый вопрос, я новичок в бутстрапе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как расположить колонки, чтобы они располагались так, как приведено на картинке.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="usr"></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="usr"></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="usr"></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comment"></label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```